# why does my for loop skips first step

Tags: java

here is my code....

```
import java.util.*;

public class lozanosjfver21 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the processes");

    int nop=sc.nextInt();
    int z=nop;
    int table1[][] = new int[z][6];
    int table2[][] = new int[z][6];

    int total = 0;
    boolean con[] = new boolean[z];
    boolean fin[] = new boolean[z];
    boolean lowest[] = new boolean[z];

    for(int a=0;a<z;a++) {
      System.out.print("Input ARRIVAL TIME and BURST TIME for process"+(a+1)+":");
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sc.nextLine());
      int b=1;
      while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        table1[a][b] = Integer.parseInt(""+st.nextToken());
        table2[a][b] = table1[a][b];
        b++;
      }
      table1[a][0] = (a+1);
      table2[a][0] = table1[a][0];
      total += table1[a][2];
      con[a] = false;
      fin[a] = false;
      lowest[a] = false;
    }
    //System.out.println(""+total);
    String str[] = new String[total];

    for(int c=0;c<total;c++) {
      /*
       * determines if a row should be considered
       * (! done and within the current time)
       */
      for(int d=0;d<z;d++) {
        if (table1[d][1]<=c&&!fin[d]) {
          con[d] = true;
        }
      }

      /*
       * determines the first low value
       * (the basis for the determining the
       * lowest value in each loop)
       */
      int low=0;
      for(int j=0;j<z;j++) {
        if(con[j]) {
          low = table1[j][2];
          break;
        }
      }

      /*
       * determines the lowest value among
       * the values considered
       */
      for(int k=0;k<z;k++) {
        if(table1[k][2]<low&&con[k]) {
          low = table1[k][2];
        }
      }

      /*
       * marks the lowest
       */
      for(int l=0;l<z;l++) {
        if(table1[l][2]==low) {
          lowest[l] = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      //this part does all the actions
      for(int f=0;f<z;f++) {
        if(lowest[f]) {
          table1[f][2] -= 1;
          if(table1[f][2]==0) {
            fin[f] = true;
            str[c] = ""+(f+1);
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      if(str[c]==null) str[c] = "0";

      //clearing
      for(int p=0;p<z;p++) {
        lowest[p] = false;
        con[p] = false;
      }
    }

    for(int n=0;n<total;n++) {
      if(str[n]!="0") {
        table2[Integer.parseInt(str[n])-1][5] = n+1;
      }
    }
    for(int t=0;t<nop;t++) {
      table2[t][4] = table2[t][5] - table2[t][1];
      table2[t][3] = table2[t][4] - table2[t][2];
    }

    System.out.println("\nP\tAT\tBT\tWT\tTT");
    for(int x=0;x<z;x++) {
      System.out.println(""+table2[x][0]+"\t"+table2[x][1]+"\t"+table2[x][2]+"\t"+table2[x][3]+"\t"+table2[x][4]+"\t");
    }
}
```

and here is the output:

```
enter the processes
4
Input ARRIVAL TIME and BURST TIME for process1:Input ARRIVAL TIME and BURST TIME for process2:0 2
Input ARRIVAL TIME and BURST TIME for process3:2 6
Input ARRIVAL TIME and BURST TIME for process4:6 5

P   AT  BT  WT  TT
1   0   0   0   0   
2   0   2   -2  0   
3   2   6   -8  -2  
4   6   5   -11 -6  

Process completed.
```

Comment: You might want to format your code! It looks like a terrible mess!!

Comment: Why are you using a `StringTokenizer` on top of a `Scanner` that already provides `nextInt()`?

Comment: Did you intend to skip `b=0`?

Comment: well the output does get displayed except for the first process...for p1 it displays everything as 0

Comment: You need to fix your code formatting and explain more.

Comment: pls help me...i need to submit this tmrw

Comment: We would love to help you, but the formatting and information of the question as it currently stands is impossible to parse.

Comment: *this* = Java? Programming? Heaving deadlines? Stackoverflow? Parsing? There are two strategies to get usefull answers: `1.` [Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) with some background information so that we can understand, what you want, what your problems are, what you have tried. `2.` Just copy&paste the code and hope for some luck. The second version is actually **not** encouraged...

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here, the formatting on your code is almost unreadable.

Arrays start at 0, so this:

```
int b=1;
```

Might need to be changed to

```
int b = 0;
```